# Redis multiple calls vs lua script

Tags: redis, lua

I have the below use case.

- Set the key with a value
- Get the key if it already exits other wise set it with a expiry.

Basically, I am trying to do a set with nx and get. Here is the lua script I came up with

```
local v = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
if v then
     return v
end
redis.call('SETEX', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])"
```

I am slightly confused whether I should use the above Lua script as compared to executing two different separate commands of get first and then set.

Any pros or cons of using the lua script. Or should two separate commands be better.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should use the script.

If you use two separate Redis commands then you'll end up with a race condition: another process might set the value after your `GET` and before your `SETEX`, causing you to overwrite it. Your logic requires this sequence of commands to be atomic, and the best way to do that in Redis is with a Lua script.

It would be possible to achieve this without the script, by using `MULTI` and `WATCH`, but the Lua script is much more straightforward.

Comment: Also with Lua script, you can save a round-trip time.

Comment: +1 for Lua for now as it has to be an atomic procedure. Look for Redis 7, it will solve it with a single `SET` command using `NX` and `GET` args.